# how to scroll my screen

Tags: java, android

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.code.zero.drivermechanicsapp.AccidentAlertFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<TextView
    android:text="Report Road Incident"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Report Road Incident"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Concern"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    tools:text="Concern"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:text="Where"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    tools:text="Where"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:text="Description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    tools:text="Description"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText4"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:maxLines="5"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:minLines="3" />

<Button
    android:text="Send S.O.S."
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:text="Phone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText3" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText4" />
```

because as i type it will block the screen. i cant even see what im typing.
and i'm really new in this android development. i don't know what to do.
can you please help me with this>?

because as i type it will block the screen. i cant even see what im typing.
and i'm really new in this android development. i don't know what to do.
can you please help me with this>?

Answer (score 0):

put your views in scrollView like below:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:text="Report Road Incident"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Report Road Incident"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Concern"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    tools:text="Concern"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:text="Where"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    tools:text="Where"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:text="Description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    tools:text="Description"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText4"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:maxLines="5"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:minLines="3" />

<Button
    android:text="Send S.O.S."
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:text="Phone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText3" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText4" />
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll your screen you simply need to do put a **ScrollView** inside your **layout**, like that:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.code.zero.drivermechanicsapp.AccidentAlertFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:text="Report Road Incident"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Report Road Incident"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:text="Concern"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    tools:text="Concern"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:text="Where"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    tools:text="Where"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:text="Description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    tools:text="Description"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText4"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:maxLines="5"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:minLines="3" />

<Button
    android:text="Send S.O.S."
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:text="Phone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText3" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/editText4" />

    </ScrollView>
```

If it says ScrollView can only have one child. **Put the children** in a single Layout like **LinearLayout**.